# I can't figure out what will happen after SELECT for NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME where age> = 15

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by

How i can write a script using a temporary table with the following fields: `NAME`, `SURNAME`, `AGE` and `OS_NAME`.

From the result of the temporary table, remove all clients whose age is less than 15 years.

As a result, display the phone's OS and the number of people who have this OS.
I can't figure out what will happen after

```py
SELECT for NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME where age> = 15
```

No time to learn `group by` my boss scolds me badly :(

Comment: You could google for `MSSQL temporary table`. Define one and insert data before selecting it with your condition like normal table.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the code you are looking for below. I would suggest taking a look at [Select (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for examples of how to write `SELECT` statements with a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as [Number of people with OS],
    OS_NAME 
FROM 
    #temptable
where 
    age >= 15
GROUP BY
    OS_NAME
```

Additionally, this query would only be relevant after you've created your temp table.